# vb.net getting the client size of an external window

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I'm currently using the GetWindowRect to get the size and location of an external window (one not in my vb.net application) as I wish to overlay my application on this external window, however, I don't want my application to lay over the titlebar or border of the external window. I would use static values for this, but if users use different themes this no longer works.

How can I find the border sizes and titlebar sizes for external windows?

I am currently using this code to overlay my application (this goes over the titlebar as well)

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowRect(ByVal hWnd As HandleRef, ByRef lpRect As RECT) As Boolean
End Function

Dim hr As New HandleRef(Process.GetProcessById(HS), Process.GetProcessById(HS).MainWindowHandle)
Dim Size As RECT
GetWindowRect(hr, Size)
Me.SetDesktopLocation(Size.X, Size.Y)
Me.Size = New Size(290, Size.Height)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GetClientRect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633503.aspx) instead of `GetWindowRect()` to get the relative coordinates of the window's client area (the area that does not include the titlebar and borders), and then use [`MapWindowPoints()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145046.aspx) to convert those relative coordinates into absolute screen coordinates, which you can then position your app within as needed.